# PCA dataset to test my implementation

Tags: pca, dataset

I'm trying to find a dataset with examples of data matrices and their principal components.

I know that I could construct my own dataset using standard implementations found in python, or octave libs, but I want to find a dataset done for other people and maybe already used on other works because I want make sure people will not think that I generated some data that "helps" my implementation.

Searching on the internet, I have found some datasets like this [one](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html), but they don't have the principal components calculated.

So, does anyone here know such dataset?

Comment: You may try googling "eigenfaces" - maybe sometimes you'll find the computed principal components. And you'll also be able to test your implementation visually

Answer (score 1):

One good and popular dataset is [Iris flower data set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set) which you can also find under your link. It has been analyzed with PCA gazillion of times, just [google for it](https://www.google.com/search?q=fisher+iris+pca&tbm=isch) or search CrossValidated (see also links given by @ttnphns in the comment below). The first principal axis of this dataset is $$(0.36,   -0.085,     0.86,     0.36),$$ as can be found by the following Matlab code:

```c
load fisheriris
X = bsxfun(@minus, meas, mean(meas));
[U,S,V] = svd(X,0);

display(num2str(V(:,1)', 2))
```

Good luck!

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/102999/3277 and http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/83114/3277 are some local illustrations of the iris data analyses - just adding to your answer.

Comment: But if it has only one pair (matrix, principal components), then, it is not very usefull to me... But, anyway, thank you very much for aswering.

Comment: @Vitor, can you please clarify what you mean by "one pair"? I don't think I understand. Also, if you need some specific features in the dataset, please edit your question to clarify these requirements.

Comment: @amoeba, of course I can  :)  It has only one data matrix, right? Then, it has only one set of principal components associated with this matrix. I would like to find several matrices with their principal components in order to run my algorithm over these matrices and compare my resulting PCs with the ones already computed.

Comment: @Vitor, Then I don't understand what you mean by "a dataset". Dataset is a data matrix, it's the same thing. Fisher Iris "data matrix" is called "dataset" by everybody! Of course it has one set of principal components.