# Toy example dataset for testing PCA implementation

Tags: pca

I want to check my implementation of dimensionality reduction with PCA, so I'm looking for a test case. I have found other implementations on the web as well, so I will be comparing with those too.

Can anyone give me a test case, where I have an $N \times D_1$ data matrix and I want to keep $D_2$ components after PCA, so let's say $N = 4$, $D_1 = 5$ and $D_2 = 3$, in other words, I have 5 features from 4 samples, and I want to do PCA and keep 3 components. Given that PCA does not have any randomness, a dataset should give the same output in different implementations of PCA, right?

If anyone is interested, what I'm doing (in MATLAB) is:

```
[COEFF,SCORE,latent] = princomp(data);
D2 = min(find((cumsum(latent)./sum(latent))>0.9)); % or simply 3 for this case
reduced_testdata = bsxfun(@minus, testdata, mean(traindata)) * COEFF;
```

**P.S:** examples for other dimensionality reduction methods (like LDA and CCA) are also very welcome, as they can help me or other users to check their code as well.

Comment: You could take iris data and follow this [example](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/102882/3277). Search this site for `iris data` to see if anybody has shown LDA, CCA with it.

Comment: Ha... I just recalled one of those was me here (LDA)http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/82497/3277. Other guys probably also created examples.

Comment: @ttnphns it must feel good to cite yourself :) and these will definitely be useful, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using Matlab, you can use `hald`:

```
% From http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/princomp.html
load hald;
[pc,score,latent,tsquare] = princomp(ingredients);
```

or `cities`, amongst [others](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/_bq9uxn4.html).

> Given that PCA does not have any randomness, a dataset should give the same output in different implementations of PCA, right?

Right, but there could be differences in rounding, some corner cases, and some functions might not sort by descending principal component scores.

Comment: The numerical sign ("+", "-") of a set of loadings (as a whole) of one factor is arbitrary and sometimes different in different implementations. For instance I normed this for my own purposes to be *"all factor loadings for the first item are positive"*. But it might be different, for instance *"the highest (absolute value) of the loadings of one factor gets the '+' sign, and the others are then adapted"* - or the direction of each factor is left simply random, just dependend on the numerical output of some part of the program.