# What is the scalings_ attribute in Linear Discriminant Analysis?

Tags: classification, python, scikit-learn

Learning to do Linear Discriminant Analysis with sklearn, and a bit confused about the `scalings_` attribute of the fitted model. The LDA classifier can be written as

$$\delta_k(x)=x^{T}\Sigma^{-1} \mu_k + C_k,$$

with $C_k$ a constant not dependent on $x$. The documentation says the scalings are the linear combinations of the predictors, so I assumed this was the $\Sigma^{-1} \mu_k$ term.

But, after fitting a LDA classifier `lda.fit(X_train,Y_train)` and comparing

`np.lingalg.inv(lda.covariance_) @ lda.means_`

`lda.scalings_`,

they are different, and I can see that I was wrong as the two results aren't the same. In fact, the first result is a $2 \times 2$ matrix, and the second result is $1 \times 2$ row vector. So, not sure where my misunderstands lie. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Please do LDA of iris data and match your results with described in an answer here https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/82497/3277. It will help understand what "scalings" are called in other software. This a good point to start from.