# Biplot computation in SVD

Tags: pca, svd, biplot

I'm trying to implement PCA biplot.

I've got much of the concepts nailed down specially thanks to:

[Relationship between SVD and PCA. How to use SVD to perform PCA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca/134283#134283)

and

[Positioning the arrows on a PCA biplot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141085/positioning-the-arrows-on-a-pca-biplot/141531#141531)

There is one last detail I just can't wrap my head around.

Given:

$X=USV^t$

I should be able to get the coordinates of my variable vectors from the columns of $V$

What I dont understand is to what variable each coordinate comes from.

X is a n sample by p variable matrix, but V is a nxn matrix

Comment: $V$ cannot possibly be an $n\times n$ matrix, because that would give $X$ $n$ columns.  $V$ usually is a $p\times p$ matrix.  When you compute fewer than $p$ PCs, such as $k\lt p$ of them, $V$ is a $p\times k$ matrix.

Comment: I'm more confused now. So the V, the right matrix should always have the same number of columns than X.

Comment: These are the rules of matrix multiplication: $X$ and $U$ *must* have the same numbers of columns; $X$ and $V^\prime$ *must* have the same numbers of rows.

Comment: Biplot and its relationship to PCA is explained also here quite comprehensively: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/141754/3277

Comment: @whuber, Thanks a lot. One las thing. Each entry of the columns of V correspond to a coordinate of my biplots. To what variable do they correspond then?

Comment: The ith entry of the columns of V corresponds to the ith column in X