# Arrows of underlying variables in PCA biplot in R

Tags: r, pca, biplot

At the risk of making the question software-specific, and with the excuse of its ubiquity and idiosyncrasies, I want to ask about the function `biplot()` in R, and, more specifically, about the calculation and plotting of its default, superimposed red arrows, corresponding to the underlying variables.

---

[To make sense of some of the comments, the plots initially posted had a sclaing problem of scarce interest, and are now erased.]

Comment: I can't figure out how you actually got your green arrows. They are not correct. The fact that the s.length green is approx. twice longer than the s.width green allows to suspect you were plotting the vectors pertaining to the variables not standardized. That cannot happen on a biplot of PCA based on correlations.

Comment: Red arrows seem correct. See: they are same length and are symmetric about PC2. That is the only possible position when you do PCA with just 2 variables and based on correlations (i.e. standardized variables). In PCA based on correlations, loadings (the coordinated of the arrows) are the correlations between the PCs and the variables. In your example, the loadings are (vars by PCs): `.74752, .66424; -.74752, .66424`.

Comment: @ttnphns Yes, the red arrows are what I'm trying to reproduce (they are correct), and they are plotted in R with the `biplot(name_of_the_PCA)` call, which in this case is `biplot(PCA)`. I had centered and scaled the data.

Comment: So, what is your question? How to compute the coordinates for the red arrows? They should be the PCA [loadings](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/143905/3277). Sometimes, eigenvectors are plotted (your R command probably did that??), however, the consensual, meaningful way [is to plot loadings](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/119746/3277).

Comment: @ttnphns Plotting the eigenvectors (I assume it's the same as the loadings) gives me the right orientation (thank you), but not the same magnitude as the red arrows (I'm pasting the image in the OP).

Comment: Antony, loadings are not eigenvectors. Please read my links. (R documentation labels eigenvectors "loadings" ... (to say it soft) ... recklessly. This issue was asked by users here million of time. Once again, my recommendation: always plot _loadings_ as the "arrows", irrespective of what R or other software does for you by default. In your PCA, the loadings must be (s.length, s.width by PC1 PC2)  `.74752, .66424; -.74752, .66424`

Comment: @AntoniParellada Did you see my answer here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141085 ? Does it clear it up?

Comment: Hmm, regarding your Edit: the little green arrows are NOT in the same direction as the red arrows. Increase their length and you will see.

Comment: I think that my linked answer should fully answer this question (I am even considering to vote to close this one as a duplicate). Maybe you can ping me here after you go over it if you still cannot make it work.

Comment: @amoeba I did see your answer yesterday... Really good! To tell you the truth, the nine combinations are throwing me off a bit, and until I see it with R I won't fully "see it". If you don't mind it, can you give some time, and see if I can come up with something (I know that code-specific Q&A are frowned upon), and I'll be the first one to delete the post if it doesn't offer anything - I'm thinking about something simpler than your answer.

Comment: Antoni, I did not mean that you should delete this question (I already upvoted it). Neither do I think that questions of the form "WTF is this statistical software doing when I run this command??" should be off-topic of frowned upon. This topic is confusing, and it took me a lot of time back then to understand what exactly R is doing here. Note that my answer mentions briefly which of the 9 combinations R uses. Starting from there, it should be pretty straightforward to reproduce the biplot that you show in this question.

Comment: @amoeba No sweat! You always help me... Thank you! I'm working on it, and I think I'm getting where I messed up to begin with...

Comment: One mistake in your original (before the Edit) code seems to be that you project the non-standardized data onto the `PCA$rotation`, whereas you should be projecting the standardized data. Regarding the scaling issue, it should be $\sqrt{150-1}$ factor -- see explanation in the same answer...

Comment: @amoeba Exactly! That is the part I had realized at the time of my prior comment - the code error. Now with the $\sqrt{150 -1}$ you just tipped me off to, it all falls in place...

Comment: @ttnphns Really sorry to bother you, again. Going over this, and realized that at no point in all the code in the answer below do I get your values above:  `.74752, .66424; -.74752, .66424`. Could you please tell me what line of code did you use?

Comment: Antoni, I didn't use R, I used SPSS. These are the loadings I got. PCA of your 2 variables was done on their correlations. Eigenvalues of the corr matrix (`r= -.11757`) were  `1.11756 .88243` and eigenvector values were all `+/- .707106`. The full iris data is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/102999/3277).

Comment: Antoni, note that in your code below you submit 3 iris data variables to PCA, not 2 variables as I did in the comments and you did in your initial question.

Comment: @ttnphns Right! Thank you... I forgot we started off with 2 variables... If I enter `X = as.matrix(iris[,1:2])` at the beginning of the code in my answer, I get your values for `loaded` (in the notation in the same chunk of code).

Answer (score 23):

> Consider upvoting [@amoeba's](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/141531/67822) and [@ttnphns' post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/119758/67822). Thank you both for your help and ideas.

---

The following relies on the [Iris dataset in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/iris.html), and specifically the first three variables (columns): `Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length`.

A **biplot** combines a **loading plot** (unstandardized eigenvectors) - in concrete, the first two *loadings*, and a **score plot** (rotated and dilated data points plotted with respect to principal components). Utilizing the same dataset, [@amoeba describes 9 possible combinations of PCA biplot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/141531/67822) based on **3 possible normalizations of the score plot** of the first and second principal components, and **3 normalizations of the loading plot (arrows)** of the initial variables. To see how R handles these possible combinations, it is interesting to look at the `biplot()` method:

---

First the linear algebra ready to copy and paste:

```
X = as.matrix(iris[,1:3])             # Three first variables of Iris dataset
CEN = scale(X, center = T, scale = T) # Centering and scaling the data
PCA = prcomp(CEN)

# EIGENVECTORS:
(evecs.ei = eigen(cor(CEN))$vectors)       # Using eigen() method
(evecs.svd = svd(CEN)$v)                   # PCA with SVD...
(evecs = prcomp(CEN)$rotation)             # Confirming with prcomp()

# EIGENVALUES:
(evals.ei = eigen(cor(CEN))$values)        # Using the eigen() method
(evals.svd = svd(CEN)$d^2/(nrow(X) - 1))   # and SVD: sing.values^2/n - 1
(evals = prcomp(CEN)$sdev^2)               # with prcomp() (needs squaring)

# SCORES:
scr.svd = svd(CEN)$u %*% diag(svd(CEN)$d)  # with SVD
scr = prcomp(CEN)$x                        # with prcomp()
scr.mm = CEN %*% prcomp(CEN)$rotation      # "Manually" [data] [eigvecs]

# LOADINGS:

loaded = evecs %*% diag(prcomp(CEN)$sdev)  # [E-vectors] [sqrt(E-values)]
```

---

### **1. Reproducing the loading plot (arrows):**

Here the geometric interpretation on [this post by @ttnphns](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/119758/67822) helps a lot. The notation of the diagram in the post has been maintained: $V$ stands for the `Sepal L.` variable in the [subject space](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/192637/67822). $h'$ is the corresponding arrow ultimately plotted; and the coordinates $a_1$ and $a_2$ are the component loads a variable $V$ with respect to $\small \text{PC} 1$ and $\small \text{PC} 2$:

---

[image]

---

The component of the variable `Sepal L.` with respect to $\small\text{PC}1$ will then be:

$$\begin{align}
a_1 &= h\cdot\cos(\phi)\\[2ex]
\end{align}$$

which, if the *scores* with respect to $\small\text{PC}1$ - let's call them $\small\text{S}1$ - are standardized so that their

$\Vert\text{S}1\Vert = \sqrt{\sum_1^n \text{scores}_1^2} = 1$, the equation above is the equivalent to the dot product $V\cdot \text{S}1$:

$$\begin{align}
a_1 &= V\cdot \text{S}1\\[2ex]
&=\Vert V\Vert\,\Vert \text{S}1\Vert\, \cos(\phi)\\[2ex]
&= h\times 1\times \cdot\cos(\phi)\tag{1}
\end{align}$$

Since $\Vert V \Vert=\sqrt{\small{\sum x^2}}$,

$$\sqrt{\small{\text{Var}(V)}}=\frac{\sqrt{\small{\sum x^2}}}{\sqrt{n-1}}=\frac{\Vert V \Vert}{\sqrt{n-1}} \implies \Vert V\Vert =h=\sqrt{\small{\text{var}(V)}} \sqrt {n-1}.$$

Likewise,

$$\Vert\text{S}1\Vert=1=\sqrt{\small \text{var(S}1)}\sqrt {n-1}.$$

Going back to Eq.$(1)$,

$$a_1=h\times 1\times \cdot\cos(\phi)=\sqrt{\small{\text{var}(V)}}\,\sqrt{\small{\text{var}(\text{S}1)}}\, \cos(\theta) \;(n-1)$$

$\cos(\phi)$ can, therefore, be considered a [Pearson's correlation coefficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/36158/67822), $r$, with the caveat that I don't understand the wrinkle of the $n-1$ factor.

Duplicating and overlapping in blue the red arrows of `biplot()`

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2)); par(mar=c(1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2))

biplot(PCA, cex = 0.6, cex.axis = .6, ann = F, tck=-0.01) # R biplot
# R biplot with overlapping (reproduced) arrows in blue completely covering red arrows:
biplot(PCA, cex = 0.6, cex.axis = .6, ann = F, tck=-0.01) 
arrows(0, 0,
       cor(X[,1], scr[,1]) * 0.8 * sqrt(nrow(X) - 1), 
       cor(X[,1], scr[,2]) * 0.8 * sqrt(nrow(X) - 1), 
       lwd = 1, angle = 30, length = 0.1, col = 4)
arrows(0, 0,
       cor(X[,2], scr[,1]) * 0.8 * sqrt(nrow(X) - 1), 
       cor(X[,2], scr[,2]) * 0.8 * sqrt(nrow(X) - 1), 
       lwd = 1, angle = 30, length = 0.1, col = 4)
arrows(0, 0,
       cor(X[,3], scr[,1]) * 0.8 * sqrt(nrow(X) - 1), 
       cor(X[,3], scr[,2]) * 0.8 * sqrt(nrow(X) - 1), 
       lwd = 1, angle = 30, length = 0.1, col = 4)
```

---

[image]

**Points of interest:**

- The arrows can be reproduced as the correlation of the original variables with the scores generated by the first two principal components.
- Alternatively, this can be achieved like in  the first plot in the second row, labeled $\mathbf{ V*S}$ in @amoeba's post:

[image]

or in R code:

```
    biplot(PCA, cex = 0.6, cex.axis = .6, ann = F, tck=-0.01) # R biplot
    # R biplot with overlapping arrows in blue completely covering red arrows:
    biplot(PCA, cex = 0.6, cex.axis = .6, ann = F, tck=-0.01) 
    arrows(0, 0,
       (svd(CEN)$v %*% diag(svd(CEN)$d))[1,1] * 0.8, 
       (svd(CEN)$v %*% diag(svd(CEN)$d))[1,2] * 0.8, 
       lwd = 1, angle = 30, length = 0.1, col = 4)
    arrows(0, 0,
       (svd(CEN)$v %*% diag(svd(CEN)$d))[2,1] * 0.8, 
       (svd(CEN)$v %*% diag(svd(CEN)$d))[2,2] * 0.8, 
       lwd = 1, angle = 30, length = 0.1, col = 4)
    arrows(0, 0,
       (svd(CEN)$v %*% diag(svd(CEN)$d))[3,1] * 0.8, 
       (svd(CEN)$v %*% diag(svd(CEN)$d))[3,2] * 0.8, 
       lwd = 1, angle = 30, length = 0.1, col = 4)
```

or even yet...

```
    biplot(PCA, cex = 0.6, cex.axis = .6, ann = F, tck=-0.01) # R biplot
    # R biplot with overlapping (reproduced) arrows in blue completely covering red arrows:
    biplot(PCA, cex = 0.6, cex.axis = .6, ann = F, tck=-0.01) 
    arrows(0, 0,
       (loaded)[1,1] * 0.8 * sqrt(nrow(X) - 1), 
       (loaded)[1,2] * 0.8 * sqrt(nrow(X) - 1), 
       lwd = 1, angle = 30, length = 0.1, col = 4)
    arrows(0, 0,
       (loaded)[2,1] * 0.8 * sqrt(nrow(X) - 1), 
       (loaded)[2,2] * 0.8 * sqrt(nrow(X) - 1), 
       lwd = 1, angle = 30, length = 0.1, col = 4)
    arrows(0, 0,
       (loaded)[3,1] * 0.8 * sqrt(nrow(X) - 1), 
       (loaded)[3,2] * 0.8 * sqrt(nrow(X) - 1), 
       lwd = 1, angle = 30, length = 0.1, col = 4)
```

connecting with the [geometric explanation of loadings by @ttnphns](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/119758/67822), or [this other informative post also by @ttnphns](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/143949/67822).

- There is a scaling factor: `sqrt(nrow(X) - 1)`, which remains a bit of a mystery.
- $0.8$ has to do with creating space for the label - see this comment [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/66933/67822):

> Further in addition, one should say that the arrows are plotted such
>   that the center of the text label is where it should be! The arrows
>   are then multiplied by 0.80.8 before plotting, i.e. all the arrows are
>   shorter than what they should be, presumably to prevent overlapping
>   with the text label (see code for biplot.default). I find this is
>   extremely confusing. – amoeba Mar 19 '15 at 10:06

---

### **2. Plotting the `biplot()` scores plot (and arrows simultaneously):**

The axes are scaled to unit sum of squares, corresponding to the [first plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ddZg.png) of the first row on [@amoeba's post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/141531/67822), which can be reproduced plotting the matrix $\mathbf U$ of the svd decomposition (more on this later) - "*Columns of $\mathbf U$: these are principal components scaled to unit sum of squares.*"

[image]

There are two different scales at play on the bottom and top horizontal axes in the biplot construction:

[image]

However the relative scale is not immediately obvious, requiring delving into the functions and methods:

`biplot()` plots scores as columns of $\mathbf U$ in SVD, which are orthogonal unit vectors:

```
> scr.svd = svd(CEN)$u %*% diag(svd(CEN)$d) 
> U = svd(CEN)$u
> apply(U, 2, function(x) sum(x^2))
[1] 1 1 1
```

Whereas the `prcomp()` function in R returns the scores scaled to their eigenvalues:

```
> apply(scr, 2, function(x) var(x))         # pr.comp() scores scaled to evals
       PC1        PC2        PC3 
2.02142986 0.90743458 0.07113557 
> evals                                     #... here is the proof:
[1] 2.02142986 0.90743458 0.07113557
```

Therefore we can scale the variance to $1$ by dividing by the eigenvalues:

```
> scr_var_one = scr/sqrt(evals)[col(scr)]  # to scale to var = 1
> apply(scr_var_one, 2, function(x) var(x)) # proved!
[1] 1 1 1
```

But since we want the sum of squares to be $1$, we'll need to divide by $\sqrt{n-1}$ because:

$$\small \text{var}(\text{scr_var_one})= 1 =\frac{\sum_1^n \text{scr_var_one}}{n -1}$$

```
> scr_sum_sqrs_one = scr_var_one / sqrt(nrow(scr) - 1) # We / by sqrt n - 1.
> apply(scr_sum_sqrs_one, 2, function(x) sum(x^2))     #... proving it...
PC1 PC2 PC3 
  1   1   1
```

Of note the use of the scaling factor $\sqrt{n-1}$, is changed later on to $\sqrt{n}$ when defining `lan` the explanation seems to lie in the fact that

> `prcomp` uses $n-1$: "Unlike princomp, variances are computed with the usual divisor $n - 1$".

---

After stripping them of all the `if` statements and other housecleaning fluff, `biplot()` proceeds as follows:

```
X   = as.matrix(iris[,1:3])                    # The original dataset
CEN = scale(X, center = T, scale = T)          # Centered and scaled
PCA = prcomp(CEN)                              # PCA analysis

par(mfrow = c(1,2))                            # Splitting the plot in 2.
biplot(PCA)                                    # In-built biplot() R func.

# Following getAnywhere(biplot.prcomp):

choices = 1:2                                  # Selecting first two PC's
scale = 1                                      # Default
scores= PCA$x                                  # The scores
lam = PCA$sdev[choices]                        # Sqrt e-vals (lambda) 2 PC's
n = nrow(scores)                               # no. rows scores
lam = lam * sqrt(n)                            # See below.

# at this point the following is called...
# biplot.default(t(t(scores[,choices])      /  lam), 
#                t(t(x$rotation[,choices]) *   lam))

# Following from now on getAnywhere(biplot.default):

x = t(t(scores[,choices])       / lam)         # scaled scores
# "Scores that you get out of prcomp are scaled to have variance equal to      
#  the eigenvalue. So dividing by the sq root of the eigenvalue (lam in 
#  biplot) will scale them to unit variance. But if you want unit sum of 
#  squares, instead of unit variance, you need to scale by sqrt(n)" (see comments).
# > colSums(x^2)
# PC1       PC2 
# 0.9933333 0.9933333    # It turns out that the it's scaled to sqrt(n/(n-1)), 
# ...rather than 1 (?) - 0.9933333=149/150

y = t(t(PCA$rotation[,choices]) * lam)         # scaled eigenvecs (loadings)


n = nrow(x)                                    # Same as dataset (150)
p = nrow(y)                                    # Three var -> 3 rows

# Names for the plotting:

xlabs = 1L:n
xlabs = as.character(xlabs)                    # no. from 1 to 150 
dimnames(x) = list(xlabs, dimnames(x)[[2L]])   # no's and PC1 / PC2

ylabs = dimnames(y)[[1L]]                      # Iris species
ylabs = as.character(ylabs)
dimnames(y) <- list(ylabs, dimnames(y)[[2L]])  # Species and PC1/PC2

# Function to get the range:
unsigned.range = function(x) c(-abs(min(x, na.rm = TRUE)), 
                                abs(max(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
rangx1 = unsigned.range(x[, 1L])               # Range first col x
# -0.1418269  0.1731236
rangx2 = unsigned.range(x[, 2L])               # Range second col x
# -0.2330564  0.2255037
rangy1 = unsigned.range(y[, 1L])               # Range 1st scaled evec
# -6.288626   11.986589
rangy2 = unsigned.range(y[, 2L])               # Range 2nd scaled evec
# -10.4776155   0.8761695

(xlim = ylim = rangx1 = rangx2 = range(rangx1, rangx2))
# range(rangx1, rangx2) = -0.2330564  0.2255037

# And the critical value is the maximum of the ratios of ranges of 
# scaled e-vectors / scaled scores:

(ratio = max(rangy1/rangx1, rangy2/rangx2)) 
# rangy1/rangx1   =   26.98328    53.15472
# rangy2/rangx2   =   44.957418   3.885388
# ratio           =   53.15472

par(pty = "s")                                 # Calling a square plot

# Plotting a box with x and y limits -0.2330564  0.2255037
# for the scaled scores:

plot(x, type = "n", xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)  # No points
# Filling in the points as no's and the PC1 and PC2 labels:
text(x, xlabs) 
par(new = TRUE)                                # Avoids plotting what follows separately

# Setting now x and y limits for the arrows:

(xlim = xlim * ratio)  # We multiply the original limits x ratio
# -16.13617  15.61324
(ylim = ylim * ratio)  # ... for both the x and y axis
# -16.13617  15.61324

# The following doesn't change the plot intially...
plot(y, axes = FALSE, type = "n", 
     xlim = xlim, 
     ylim = ylim, xlab = "", ylab = "")

# ... but it does now by plotting the ticks and new limits...
# ... along the top margin (3) and the right margin (4)
axis(3); axis(4)
text(y, labels = ylabs, col = 2)  # This just prints the species

arrow.len = 0.1                   # Length of the arrows about to plot.

# The scaled e-vecs are further reduced to 80% of their value
arrows(0, 0, y[, 1L] * 0.8, y[, 2L] * 0.8, 
       length = arrow.len, col = 2)
```

which, as expected, reproduces (right image below) the `biplot()` output as called directly with `biplot(PCA)` (left plot below) in all its untouched aesthetic shortcomings:

[image]

**Points of interest:**

- The arrows are plotted at a scale related to the maximum ratio between the scaled eigenvector of each one of the two principal components and their respective scaled scores (the `ratio`). AS @amoeba comments:

> the scatter plot and the "arrow plot" are scaled such that the largest (in absolute value) x or y arrow coordinate of the arrows was exactly equal to the largest (in absolute value) x or y coordinate of the scattered data points

- As anticipated above, the points can be directly plotted as the scores in the matrix $\mathbf U$ of the SVD:

---

Comment: +1, Good study. I added tag `R` to your question because the confusing matter (namely, the scaling coefficient) proved to be partly R-specific. In general, you were able to see yourself that PCA biplot is a overlay scatterplot of component scores (row coordinates) and component direction coefficients (column coordinates), and since various amounts od standardizations by "inertia" (variance) may be applied to each of the too, so various looks of the biplot may arise. To add: most typically (more sense), _loadings_ are displayed as the column coordinates (arrows).

Comment: (cont.)  See my overview of [biplot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/141755/3277) which explains, in different words, what you've shown in your nice answer.

Comment: + 1 thanks for writing tutorials and with reproducible code for us!

Comment: Antony, did you draw (as by hand) or did you plot (fed in data) your pic? What software did you use? It looks nice.

Comment: @ttnphns Thank you! [Here's the link to it](https://ggbm.at/UtkvBTY9). I was wondering if you would could improve on it, and plot the loadings and the PC's in a better, more didactic way. Feel free to change (it's a wonderfully user-friendly program), and if you do, please share.

Comment: Don't you want to mark this as accepted @Antoni? It's a great post by now.

Answer (score 1):

The `biplot()` function following a PCA using `prcomp()` is minimal in functionality. As we all (should) know, `ggplot()` offers maximal functionality. So the trick is to get the arrows from a PCA using `prcomp()` into a format for plotting in `ggplot()`. Or at least I would see this as a solution to the initial question of this thread.

This is relatively straightforward. Note that my post is partially inspired by this [post](https://www.benjaminbell.co.uk/2018/02/principal-components-analysis-pca-in-r.html) from Benjamin Bell. Also, the iris data are not necessarily ideal for this, but should provide enough for the user to see the potential here.

R Code

```
`library("tidyverse",
    "ggplot2")

# Load iris data
iris <- iris

# Select variables to run PCA
iris_pca <- select(iris, -Species)

# PCA with prcomp
m1 <- prcomp(iris_pca, center = T, scale = T)

# Get principal loadings of first two components
iris$PC1 <- predict(m1, newdata = iris)[,1]
iris$PC2 <- predict(m1, newdata = iris)[,2]

# Get arrow end point locations (loadings*2 for effect)
l.x <- m1$rotation[,1]*2
l.y <- m1$rotation[,2]*2

# Get label positions (%15 further than end of arrows)
l.posx <- l.x*1.15
l.posy <- l.y*1.15

# Get labels for plot (variable names)
l.labels <- row.names(m1$rotation)

# Plot with grouping by flower
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = iris, aes(PC1, PC2, color = Species), size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#287D8EFF", "#482677FF", "#20A387FF")) + #colorblind pal
  geom_segment(aes(x=0, y=0, xend = l.x, yend = l.y), 
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm"), type = "closed"),
               color = "darkorange4") +
  geom_text(aes(x = l.posx, y = l.posy, label = l.labels), 
            color = "darkorange4", size = 2, hjust = 0) + # labels
  theme_classic()

# Packages
sessionInfo()`
```

[image]

Packages and versions:

cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.7.0     compiler_4.1.3   dbplyr_2.1.1     tools_4.1.3
digest_0.6.29    jsonlite_1.8.0   lubridate_1.8.0  lifecycle_1.0.1  gtable_0.3.0
pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_1.0.2      reprex_2.0.1     rstudioapi_0.13  DBI_1.1.2
cli_3.2.0        haven_2.4.3      xml2_1.3.3       withr_2.5.0      httr_1.4.2      fs_1.5.2         generics_0.1.2   vctrs_0.3.8      hms_1.1.1        grid_4.1.3
tidyselect_1.1.2 glue_1.6.2       R6_2.5.1         fansi_1.0.3      readxl_1.4.0
farver_2.1.0     tzdb_0.3.0       modelr_0.1.8     magrittr_2.0.2   backports_1.4.1
scales_1.1.1     ellipsis_0.3.2   rvest_1.0.2      assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_2.0-3
labeling_0.4.2   utf8_1.2.2       stringi_1.7.6    munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.7.12
crayon_1.5.1

Comment: Nice plot! Not a big fan of ggplot() esthetic feel in general, but I am just curious about data - not in the data/statistics field professionally - and I like to stick to the basic R functions with as few packages as possible.