# How do you interpret the result of pca and biplot?

Tags: pca

```
          PC1   PC2   PC3
```

Electricity -0.48  0.12 -0.77

Fertility    0.49 -0.04  0.11

Life_exp    -0.50 -0.01  0.51

Pop_dens    -0.12 -0.99 -0.07

Child_mort   0.51 -0.08 -0.35

[image]

Questions:
Do you need to use absolute value for PC1?  I am kind of confused. Electricity and Life exp are roughly equal weight, Child_mort and Fertility are roughly equal weight as well. (If I get it right) If you use absolute value for PC1, does that mean you have four features I just mentioned are roughly equal weight?

How do you interpret PC2?

Comment: check my answer here : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66926/what-are-the-four-axes-on-pca-biplot

Comment: @HaitaoDu 感谢您的回答并且看到了您的附加的链接，但我还是没有太明白。 因为我的问题是在 PC1 里面 electricity 和 life_exp 权重大概 相等 但是 fertility 和 Child Mortality 的值也很相似， 而 Pop Density的权重比较小。 那这个主成分大致上 解释了什么？如果用绝对值来看 PC2的话 是否PC2里 pop density 的权重是最大的 其他变量的权重较小。那在PC2 的主成分又如何解释？  非常感谢您的帮助，同时看到了您在领英的信息，注意到您在西电上过大学，彷佛找到了老乡:)

Comment: Nice to see comments in Chinese. In fact, your question is not really clear for me. If you want try to contact me in private messages and I can call you and speak over phone to explain if you want.