# How can to visualize/plot correlation matrix as a distance matrix of points in space?

Tags: correlation, pca, data-visualization, distance

It seems to me that the various options for visualizing the correlation matrix in R are quite unintuitive for laymen. They focus on the graphical representation of the correlation matrix as different colors or shapes of the correlation coefficient - and I am thinking of representing them in terms of distance from each other. We visualize the distances between points, for example, using factor analysis or other analyses. **How to create a graph/plot from a ready-made symmetrical correlation matrix in which the greater the distance, the smaller the correlation? What data transformation to use?**

For start, because I want to show the "similarity" between the variables, I have such an assumption that the correlation at level 1 is the highest correlation and the distance from the points is zero, and the correlation -1 is the lowest correlation, i.e. the maximum distance from the points. But I'll also settle for a graph where negative correlations will be treated the same as positive correlations. I am asking for an example in R, because only in it I can create visualizations, or just the name of the technique that I could search for. Thanks in advance for all hints.

Comment: Biplots from principal component analysis (e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137240/how-to-interpret-this-pca-biplot) are often used for this purpose. Tastes vary, but to me a scatter plot matrix is more informative than anything like a biplot -- which rests entirely on correlation being an adequate summary of each bivariate relationship.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for an (approximate) isometric embedding of points on a high-dimensional sphere into the plane.  Most of the time that won't work well; but if it might, various MDS methods should be able to find one.