# Interpreting PCA figures in layman terms

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, interpretation, dimensionality-reduction

Image you have to present your PCA findings to a managerial board. An example:

[image]

After having read answers from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2038/interpretation-of-biplots-in-principal-components-analysis), I've understood that

- The left and bottom axis are correlations
- The right and upper are the weights (i.e. loadings)

However, even after reading the other posts, it’s hard for me to interpret the results, let alone imagining how to present them in a meeting.

My questions:

1. Is the upper axis bound to PC1, and the right axis to PC2?
2. Features `Attack` + `HitPoints` mostly influence PC1 but
   `Speed` both PCs (correlated *positively* to both PCs) and `Defense` also both (but correlated *negatively* to PC2?)?
3. The model was done with R's `prcomp`. None of the model's printable values (i.e., `x`, `sdev`, `scale`, `center` and `rotation`) are remotely close to **-8 to 6** as illustrated in the upper and right axis in the figure. Why? Any way to print the exact values of the upper and right axis?

Here's the full data assigned to a given variable called **pokemon** from an online tutorial:

```
                          HitPoints Attack Defense Speed
Quilava                        58     64      58    80
Goodra                         90    100      70    80
Mothim                         70     94      50    66
Marowak                        60     80     110    45
Chandelure                     60     55      90    80
Helioptile                     44     38      33    70
MeloettaAria Forme            100     77      77    90
MetagrossMega Metagross        80    145     150   110
Sawsbuck                       80    100      70    95
Probopass                      60     55     145    40
GiratinaAltered Forme         150    100     120    90
Tranquill                      62     77      62    65
Simisage                       75     98      63   101
Scizor                         70    130     100    65
Jigglypuff                    115     45      20    20
Carracosta                     74    108     133    32
Ferrothorn                     74     94     131    20
Kadabra                        40     35      30   105
Sylveon                        95     65      65    60
Golem                          80    120     130    45
Magnemite                      25     35      70    45
Vanillish                      51     65      65    59
Unown                          48     72      48    48
Snivy                          45     45      55    63
Tynamo                         35     55      40    60
Duskull                        20     40      90    25
Beautifly                      60     70      50    65
Marill                         70     20      50    40
Lunatone                       70     55      65    70
Flygon                         80    100      80   100
Bronzor                        57     24      86    23
Monferno                       64     78      52    81
Simisear                       75     98      63   101
Aromatisse                    101     72      72    29
Scraggy                        50     75      70    48
Scolipede                      60    100      89   112
Staraptor                      85    120      70   100
GyaradosMega Gyarados          95    155     109    81
Tyrunt                         58     89      77    48
Zekrom                        100    150     120    90
Gyarados                       95    125      79    81
Cobalion                       91     90     129   108
Espurr                         62     48      54    68
Spheal                         70     40      50    25
Dodrio                         60    110      70   100
Torkoal                        70     85     140    20
Cacnea                         50     85      40    35
Trubbish                       50     50      62    65
Lucario                        70    110      70    90
GiratinaOrigin Forme          150    120     100    90
```

This is the whole code I used in the online tutorial environment:

```
> typeof(pokemon)
[1] "integer"
> pca <- prcomp(pokemon, scale = T, center = T)
> biplot(pca)
```

Comment: The OP has stated what they understood from the duplicate & what they still don't understand. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: A PCA biplot is an overlay scatterplot of component loadings and component data point scores in the space of the (usually first two) components. Axes could be gauged by different scales depending on whether the "loadings" are loadings or eigenvectors and whether the scores are raw or standardized (unit variance). Without data and syntax it may be difficult to figure out at once what are the scales of your axes. I might recommend you - if you want a concrete guidance - to post data (at least) plus the syntax.

Comment: @ttnphns: added data and the little code scippet

Comment: `The left and bottom axis are correlations` - this is wrong. As written in the linked thread, bottom/left axes show normalized (to unit sum of squares) PC1 and PC2 scores. Regarding your questions, (1) Yes, (2) Yes, (3) These values correspond to PCA eigenvectors (that you see in the `prcomp` output) scaled by the PCA eigenvalues and scaled further by the $\sqrt{n}$. All of that is extensively covered on our website and some relevant threads are linked in the thread you read, e.g. see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141085.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The link ( http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141085 ) provided in the comments give great insight. In this post I place some additions and specific comments on the particular biplot function used

- I especially recommend you to **look at the documentation** of the biplot function (in a R console type "`?biplot.princomp`"). In that documentation you will read that the biplot is based on:

  Gabriel, K. R. (1971). The biplot graphical display of matrices with applications to principal component analysis. *Biometrika*, **58**, 453–467.
  [link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2334381)

  Also the documentation explains you that there are several options to alter the appearance of the plot. For instance your question 1 *"Is the upper axis bound to PC1, and the right axis to PC2?"* relates to the 'choices' parameter in the function. You can choose different PCs to be on the x and y axis.
- As well it is worthwhile to **look at the source code** of the biplot:

  ```r
  > getS3method("biplot","prcomp")
  function (x, choices = 1L:2L, scale = 1, pc.biplot = FALSE, ...) 
  {
    if (length(choices) != 2L) 
      stop("length of choices must be 2")
    if (!length(scores <- x$x)) 
        stop(gettextf("object '%s' has no scores", deparse(substitute(x))), 
            domain = NA)
    if (is.complex(scores)) 
        stop("biplots are not defined for complex PCA")
    lam <- x$sdev[choices]
    n <- NROW(scores)
    lam <- lam * sqrt(n)
    if (scale < 0 || scale > 1) 
        warning("'scale' is outside [0, 1]")
    if (scale != 0) 
        lam <- lam^scale
    else lam <- 1
    if (pc.biplot) 
        lam <- lam/sqrt(n)
    biplot.default(t(t(scores[, choices])/lam), t(t(x$rotation[, 
        choices]) * lam), ...)
    invisible()
  }
  <bytecode: 0x62870ca8>
  <environment: namespace:stats>
  ```

  with this source code you won't have any confusion about what type of scaling is used (e.g., see that a factor $\sqrt{n}$ is used instead of $\sqrt{n-1}$, the latter being mentioned in an answer to the earlier mentioned question)

  Also this scaling stuff answers your question 3. The princomp scales everything by the standard deviation. And the biplot does another scaling with $\sqrt{50}$ as well as the eigenvalues $\lambda$.
- The 2d (bi-)plots are essentially projections of multidimensional data. I always believe that a 3d view of PCA is a great help to understand that, and I hope that the following two images may provide you some additional insight for you.

  While your data is 4d I took the liberty to eliminate 1 of your
  variables in order to make the plotting possible. You will have to
  try to extend this idea to some imagination of a higher order
  dimensional space.

  The biplot:

  ```r
  pok<-matrix(c("Quilava",58,64,58,80,
  "Goodra",90,100,70,80,
  "Mothim",70,94,50,66,
  "Marowak",60,80,110,45,
  "Chandelure",60,55,90,80,
  "Helioptile",44,38,33,70,
  "MeloettaAriaForme",100,77,77,90,
  "MetagrossMega",80,145,150,110,
  "Sawsbuck",80,100,70,95,
  "Probopass",60,55,145,40,
  "GiratinaAltered",150,100,120,90,
  "Tranquill",62,77,62,65,
  "Simisage",75,98,63,101,
  "Scizor",70,130,100,65,
  "Jigglypuff",115,45,20,20,
  "Carracosta",74,108,133,32,
  "Ferrothorn",74,94,131,20,
  "Kadabra",40,35,30,105,
  "Sylveon",95,65,65,60,
  "Golem",80,120,130,45,
  "Magnemite",25,35,70,45,
  "Vanillish",51,65,65,59,
  "Unown",48,72,48,48,
  "Snivy",45,45,55,63,
  "Tynamo",35,55,40,60,
  "Duskull",20,40,90,25,
  "Beautifly",60,70,50,65,
  "Marill",70,20,50,40,
  "Lunatone",70,55,65,70,
  "Flygon",80,100,80,100,
  "Bronzor",57,24,86,23,
  "Monferno",64,78,52,81,
  "Simisear",75,98,63,101,
  "Aromatisse",101,72,72,29,
  "Scraggy",50,75,70,48,
  "Scolipede",60,100,89,112,
  "Staraptor",85,120,70,100,
  "GyaradosMega",95,155,109,81,
  "Tyrunt",58,89,77,48,
  "Zekrom",100,150,120,90,
  "Gyarados",95,125,79,81,
  "Cobalion",91,90,129,108,
  "Espurr",62,48,54,68,
  "Spheal",70,40,50,25,
  "Dodrio",60,110,70,100,
  "Torkoal",70,85,140,20,
  "Cacnea",50,85,40,35,
  "Trubbish",50,50,62,65,
  "Lucario",70,110,70,90,
  "GiratinaOrigin",150,120,100,90),50,byrow=1)

  pokt <- matrix(as.numeric(pok[,-1]),50)
  pokn <- pok[,1]         

  biplot(pca,scale=1,xlabs=pokn,ylabs=c("attack","defense","speed"),cex=0.7,xlab="",ylab="")
  mtext("PCA2 loading of vectors\n multiplied by lambda*sqrt(n)", side=4, line=3)
  mtext("PCA1 loading of vectors\n multiplied by lambda*sqrt(n)", side=3, line=2.5)
  mtext("PCA2 scores\n divided by lambda*sqrt(n)", side=2, line=2.5)
  mtext("PCA1 scores\n divided by lambda*sqrt(n)", side=1, line=3)
  ```

[image: 2d biplot]
[image: 3d biplot]

- You should try to see for yourself whether you can recognize the 2d-biplot in the 3d-image.
- Note in the 3d image how the points as well as axes(attack, defense, speed) are projected onto the plane spanned by the PC1 and PC2 vectors.
- points as well as axes (Geometrically a biplot is this two-times projection, showing two things together: the transformed vectors, loadings, as well as the transformed points, scores. Algebraically the biplot is the dual representation of the singular value decomposition matrices $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$, ands scaled versions thereof.
- in the 3d image the scales do not match the same as the scales in the 2d image. That's because in the 3d image we project both loadings and scores on the same plane, with the same scale in 3d (and we adjust the scales on the edges of the 2d plane), and in the 2d images those scales are placed on different axes allowing to stretch them such that the min and max of the scales coincide$

codeblock for animation (excuse for the dirty writing with little spaces etcetera):

```r
    # centering and scaling
    pokt <- apply(pokt,2, FUN <- function(v) {(v-mean(v))/sqrt(var(v))} )

    # loading libraries (not sure all are needed)
    library("plotrix")
    library(plot3D)
    library(rgl)    
    library(matlib) 

    # prepare rgl device
    #rgl.close() # for debugging
    rgl.open() # Open a new RGL device
    bgplot3d({
      plot.new()
      title(main = '', line = 3)
    })
    par3d(windowRect = 50 + c( 0, 0, 800, 800 ) )
    rgl.bg(color = "#fcfbf6")
    rgl.viewpoint(theta = -90, phi = 20, zoom = 1)


    # plot data points
    rgl.points(pokt[,2], pokt[,3], pokt[,4], color ="blue",size=5)

    # axes and square box
    N = 2.5

    rgl.lines(c(-N, N), c(-N, -N),c(-N, -N), color = "gray")
    rgl.lines(c(-N, -N), c(-N,N), c(-N, -N), color = "gray")
    rgl.lines(c(-N, -N), c(-N, -N), c(-N,N), color = "gray")
    rgl.lines(c(N, -N), c(N, N), c(N, N), color = "gray")
    rgl.lines(c(N, N), c(N, -N), c(N, N), color = "gray")
    rgl.lines(c(N, N), c(N, N), c(N, -N), color = "gray")
    rgl.lines(c(N, N), c(-N, -N), c(N, -N), color = "gray")
    rgl.lines(c(N, -N), c(N, N), c(-N, -N), color = "gray")
    rgl.lines(c(-N, -N), c(-N, N), c(N, N), color = "gray")
    rgl.lines(c(N, -N), c(-N, -N), c(N, N), color = "gray")
    rgl.lines(c(N, N), c(N, -N), c(-N, -N), color = "gray")
    rgl.lines(c(-N, -N), c(N, N), c(N, -N), color = "gray")

    rgl.lines(c(0, N), c(0, 0),c(0, 0), color = "orange")
    rgl.lines(c(0, 0), c(0, N),c(0, 0), color = "orange")
    rgl.lines(c(0, 0), c(0, 0),c(0, N), color = "orange")
    cone3d(base=c(N,0,0)*0.94,tip=c(N,0,0)*0.06,radius=0.1,col="orange")
    cone3d(base=c(0,N,0)*0.94,tip=c(0,N,0)*0.06,radius=0.1,col="orange")
    cone3d(base=c(0,0,N)*0.94,tip=c(0,0,N)*0.06,radius=0.1,col="orange")

    rgl.texts(c(c(N,0,0),c(0,N,0),c(0,0,N)),
              text = c("attack","defense","speed"), color="orange",
              adj = c(0.0, 0.0), size = 9)

    # biplot calculations
    lam <- pca$sdev[]*sqrt(50)
    scores <-  cbind(pokt[,2],pokt[,3],pokt[,4]) %*% pca$rotation
    scores_sm <- scores %*% diag(lam^-1)

    loadings <- pca$rotation
    loadings_sm <- loadings %*% diag(lam)

    # 2d plot in 3d

       # define boundaries
    max1 <- max(scores[,1])*1.1
    max2 <- max(scores[,2])*1.1
    min1 <- min(scores[,1])*1.1
    min2 <- min(scores[,2])*1.1

       # plot bounding box of biplot
    rgl.lines(c(+max1*pca$rotation[1,1]+max2*pca$rotation[1,2], -max1*pca$rotation[1,1]+max2*pca$rotation[1,2]),
              c(+max1*pca$rotation[2,1]+max2*pca$rotation[2,2], -max1*pca$rotation[2,1]+max2*pca$rotation[2,2]),
              c(+max1*pca$rotation[3,1]+max2*pca$rotation[3,2], -max1*pca$rotation[3,1]+max2*pca$rotation[3,2]),
              color = "black")
    rgl.lines(c(+max1*pca$rotation[1,1]-max2*pca$rotation[1,2], -max1*pca$rotation[1,1]-max2*pca$rotation[1,2]),
              c(+max1*pca$rotation[2,1]-max2*pca$rotation[2,2], -max1*pca$rotation[2,1]-max2*pca$rotation[2,2]),
              c(+max1*pca$rotation[3,1]-max2*pca$rotation[3,2], -max1*pca$rotation[3,1]-max2*pca$rotation[3,2]),
              color = "black")
    rgl.lines(c(+max1*pca$rotation[1,1]+max2*pca$rotation[1,2], +max1*pca$rotation[1,1]-max2*pca$rotation[1,2]),
              c(+max1*pca$rotation[2,1]+max2*pca$rotation[2,2], +max1*pca$rotation[2,1]-max2*pca$rotation[2,2]),
              c(+max1*pca$rotation[3,1]+max2*pca$rotation[3,2], +max1*pca$rotation[3,1]-max2*pca$rotation[3,2]),
              color = "black")
    rgl.lines(c(-max1*pca$rotation[1,1]+max2*pca$rotation[1,2], -max1*pca$rotation[1,1]-max2*pca$rotation[1,2]),
              c(-max1*pca$rotation[2,1]+max2*pca$rotation[2,2], -max1*pca$rotation[2,1]-max2*pca$rotation[2,2]),
              c(-max1*pca$rotation[3,1]+max2*pca$rotation[3,2], -max1*pca$rotation[3,1]-max2*pca$rotation[3,2]),
              color = "black")

    # plot projected points
    projected_points <- scores[,c(1,2)] %*% t(pca$rotation[,c(1,2)])
    rgl.points(projected_points[,1],projected_points[,2],projected_points[,3], color ="black",size=5)

    # plot projection paths for points
    for (i in 1:50) {
      rgl.lines(c(pokt[i,2], projected_points[i,1]),
                c(pokt[i,3], projected_points[i,2]),
                c(pokt[i,4], projected_points[i,3]), color = "gray")
    }

    # plot projected loadings axes
    projected_lines <- N*loadings[,c(1,2)] %*% t(pca$rotation)[c(1,2),]

    rgl.lines(c(0,projected_lines[1,1]),
              c(0,projected_lines[1,2]),
              c(0,projected_lines[1,3]), color="red")

    rgl.lines(c(0,projected_lines[2,1]),
              c(0,projected_lines[2,2]),
              c(0,projected_lines[2,3]), color="red")

    rgl.lines(c(0,projected_lines[3,1]),
              c(0,projected_lines[3,2]),
              c(0,projected_lines[3,3]), color="red")


    # plot tickmarks
    for (i in -3:3) {
      pos = i/10*sqrt(50)*pca$sdev[2]
      rgl.lines(c(-max1*pca$rotation[1,1]+pos*pca$rotation[1,2], -1.05*max1*pca$rotation[1,1]+pos*pca$rotation[1,2]),
                c(-max1*pca$rotation[2,1]+pos*pca$rotation[2,2], -1.05*max1*pca$rotation[2,1]+pos*pca$rotation[2,2]),
                c(-max1*pca$rotation[3,1]+pos*pca$rotation[3,2], -1.05*max1*pca$rotation[3,1]+pos*pca$rotation[3,2]),
                color = "black") 
      rgl.texts(-1.08*max1*pca$rotation[1,1]+pos*pca$rotation[1,2],
               -1.08*max1*pca$rotation[2,1]+pos*pca$rotation[2,2],
               -1.08*max1*pca$rotation[3,1]+pos*pca$rotation[3,2],
               text=i/10,color="black")
    }

    for (i in -3:3) {
      pos = i/10*sqrt(50)*pca$sdev[1]
      rgl.lines(c(-max2*pca$rotation[1,2]+pos*pca$rotation[1,1], -1.06*max2*pca$rotation[1,2]+pos*pca$rotation[1,1]),
                c(-max2*pca$rotation[2,2]+pos*pca$rotation[2,1], -1.06*max2*pca$rotation[2,2]+pos*pca$rotation[2,1]),
                c(-max2*pca$rotation[3,2]+pos*pca$rotation[3,1], -1.06*max2*pca$rotation[3,2]+pos*pca$rotation[3,1]),
                color = "black") 
      rgl.texts(-1.1*max2*pca$rotation[1,2]+pos*pca$rotation[1,1],
                -1.1*max2*pca$rotation[2,2]+pos*pca$rotation[2,1],
                -1.1*max2*pca$rotation[3,2]+pos*pca$rotation[3,1],
                text=i/10,color="black")
    }

    for (i in -3:2) {
      pos = N*i*2/sqrt(50)/pca$sdev[1]
      rgl.lines(c(max2*pca$rotation[1,2]+pos*pca$rotation[1,1], 1.05*max2*pca$rotation[1,2]+pos*pca$rotation[1,1]),
                c(max2*pca$rotation[2,2]+pos*pca$rotation[2,1], 1.05*max2*pca$rotation[2,2]+pos*pca$rotation[2,1]),
                c(max2*pca$rotation[3,2]+pos*pca$rotation[3,1], 1.05*max2*pca$rotation[3,2]+pos*pca$rotation[3,1]),
                color = "red") 
      rgl.texts(1.08*max2*pca$rotation[1,2]+pos*pca$rotation[1,1],
                1.08*max2*pca$rotation[2,2]+pos*pca$rotation[2,1],
                1.08*max2*pca$rotation[3,2]+pos*pca$rotation[3,1],
                text=i*2,color="red")
    }

    for (i in -3:2) {
      pos = N*i*2/sqrt(50)/pca$sdev[2]
      rgl.lines(c(max1*pca$rotation[1,1]+pos*pca$rotation[1,2], 1.05*max1*pca$rotation[1,1]+pos*pca$rotation[1,2]),
                c(max1*pca$rotation[2,1]+pos*pca$rotation[2,2], 1.05*max1*pca$rotation[2,1]+pos*pca$rotation[2,2]),
                c(max1*pca$rotation[3,1]+pos*pca$rotation[3,2], 1.05*max1*pca$rotation[3,1]+pos*pca$rotation[3,2]),
                color = "red") 
      rgl.texts(1.08*max1*pca$rotation[1,1]+pos*pca$rotation[1,2],
                1.08*max1*pca$rotation[2,1]+pos*pca$rotation[2,2],
                1.08*max1*pca$rotation[3,1]+pos*pca$rotation[3,2],
                text=i*2,color="red")
    }

    # make movei and close device
    movie3d(spin3d(axis = c(0, 1, 0),rpm=-7.5), duration = 8, fps=10, dir = "~/gif")
    rgl.close()
```

Comment: +1 the animation is very nice, Can you share the code of making it?

Comment: I have added the code. I hope it works out of the box (library stuff etcetera). The nice thing is that if you run this on your computer then it becomes interactive (using the mouse). The problem with the video is that it is difficult to follow. Maybe one day stackexchange will have inclusion of interactive plots?

Comment: thanks, I learned a lot from the code. I used to save a bunch of pictures and use online tools to convert to gif. Your code is definitely better!